Power Automate Flow - Create a new folder from PowerApps - Folder Path?
I am trying to have a Canvas app create a new folder in a library, but in the Create a New Folder action, "ask in powerapps" is no longer available.  How can I populate the folder path without it?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Use Power Apps (V2) trigger where you can define the text input for your folder path and pass the input from app to flow. Let me know if it works for you.

If you want to pass some information (like "folder path") from Canvas Power Apps to your Power automate flow, I will suggest you to use the "Power Apps (V2)" trigger. Try following these steps:

Go to your Power automate flow.

If you have used "Power Apps" trigger, delete it.

Add "Power Apps (V2)" trigger.

Add new text input for "Folder Path"

Use this folder path input in your further flow actions

While calling flow from Power Apps using .Run() method, you can pass inputs/parameters to the flow.


Example:

Check this article for detailed information about this Power Apps (V2) trigger: Power Automate: Power Apps (V2) Trigger.

THANK YOU.  that's what I was looking for.  I've got the app/flow creating the new doc set successfully.  Second question, if I want more fields (due date field, people picker, etc.) from the App to populate as metadata in that new Doc Set, do I need to add Inputs for each (like I did for Folder Path)?

Yes, you can add multiple inputs and pass the data from app to flow.
